# Add_Element_0: идентификатор не найден

Tags: c++

```
void Insert_Element(Node** head, int Number, int numberofthings, int ticket_code, string last_name, string luggage_weight, int day, int month, int year)
{
  Number--;
  Node* NewItem = new Node;
  NewItem->data.numberofthings = numberofthings;
  NewItem->data.ticket_code = ticket_code;
  NewItem->data.last_name = last_name;
  NewItem->data.luggage_weight = luggage_weight;
  NewItem->data.date.day = day;
  NewItem->data.date.month = month;
  NewItem->data.date.year = year;
  NewItem->next = NULL;

  if ((*head) == NULL)
  {

    (*head) = NewItem;
  }

  else {
    Node* Current = (*head);
    for (int i = 1; i < Number && Current->next != NULL; i++)
      Current = Current->next;
    if (Number == 0) {

      Add_Element_0(&(*head), numberofthings, ticket_code, last_name, luggage_weight, day, month, year);
    }
    else {
      if (Current->next != NULL)
        NewItem->next = Current->next;
      Current->next = NewItem;
    }
  }
}
void Add_Element_0(Node** head, int numberofthings, int ticket_code, string last_name, string luggage_weight, int day, int month, int year)
{

  Node* NewItem = new Node;
  NewItem->data.numberofthings = numberofthings;
  NewItem->data.ticket_code = ticket_code;
  NewItem->data.last_name = last_name;
  NewItem->data.luggage_weight = luggage_weight;
  NewItem->data.date.day = day;
  NewItem->data.date.month = month;
  NewItem->data.date.year = year;
  NewItem->next = (*head);

  (*head) = NewItem;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В си и с++ (да и в большинстве языков) функции нужно объявлять до их использования. А у Вас наоборот. Просто передвиньте функцию Add_Element_0 выше функции Insert_Element. Или используйте предварительное объявление просто перед функцией Insert_Element добавьте строку

```
void Add_Element_0(Node** head, int numberofthings, int ticket_code, string last_name, string luggage_weight, int day, int month, int year);
```

Comment: прикольно, и полночь минусаторы не спят. Мне вот интересно, почему у них бессонница:)